# How to copy specific items from a 2d vector using copy_if

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

As an example, I have a 2d vector and a 1d vector and I want to copy the first item from each row using **std::copy_if** from the algorithm library:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> names{ { "Allan", "Daniel", "Maria" }, {"John", "Louis", "Will"}, {"Bill", "Joe", "Nick"}};
```

So we'll have to copy "Allan", "John" and "Bill" into the destination vector which is dst

```
std::vector<std::string> dst;
```

Comment: why `copy_if` ? Is that a hard requirement? I dont understand what would be the `_if` here

Comment: It is a good practice for using less code.

Comment: using algorithms is good practice, but I am asking, why specifically `copy_if` ? I thought maybe you have a reason to ask for that, if not and this was just your first guess, also ok, I am just curious

Comment: also sometimes code here is simplified to an extend that the actual motivation is hard to see, so it could have been that you have a case where you actually do need to use `copy_if` and only in the code here it is not apparent anymore. Nevermind, seems like you got what you were looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `std::transform` instead of `std::copy_if`:

```cpp
std::transform(names.begin(), names.end(), std::back_inserter(dst),
    [](const std::vector<std::string>& v) { return v[0]; });
```

Comment: Because the destination and the source `vector` don't have the same type. You need to transform from one into another

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the appropriate algorithm for your task. `std::copy_if` copies elements of a range *if* that element satisfies some predicate.

This might seem like you need to use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), but that would be an issue because *copy* simply means, copy each element unconditionally.

In your case, the appropriate algorithm would be [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), since you want to transform each element of the range into a different type.

```
std::vector<std::string> dst;
std::transform(names.begin(), names.end(),
               std::back_inserter(dst), /* function */);
```

where `function` would be a lambda that returns just the first `string` from a `vector<string>`.